# <TextInput /> not editable in react-native/expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am learnig React-native, I create an app using Expo.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet, View, Button, TouchableOpacity, Platform, TextInput } from 'react-native';

const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    const [platform, setPlatform] = useState('');
    const [age, setAge] = useState('35')
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
           <Text>Enter Age</Text>

           <TextInput 
            style={styles.input}
            value={age}
            onChangeText = {(val) => {
                console.log(val)
                setAge(val)
            }}/>
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    input: {
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#777',
        padding: 8,
        margin: 10,
        width: 200,
        height: 35
    }
});

export default HomeScreen;
```

Here everything is working properly, but  is not editable, in android device as well as Genymotion.

Please help.

Comment: try to put a return before setAge maybe.

Comment: Try removing `padding` and `margin` from your `input` style.

Comment: @Raju, I run your code,it's working fine in the expo. What do you actually need to try. please explain with screenshots

Comment: @Asad, actually the problem comes when I use this HomeScreen , into App.js like this <HomeScreen  props="..." />. Then input becomes non-editable inside HomeScreen.